# I am Not getting map view in my app after publishing it on play store so what shoud i do?

Tags: android, google-maps

after publishing app on the play store I am not getting map view on google map which in my application. i am getting lat-long which are required for map from database. It is working properly and showing the map view in application when app is directly get installed on my device from android studio. but it giving me a problem when app get installed from play store. I have used Google API key. so is anyone knows about this issue..?

Comment: Did you updated key which is supposed to be generate with released keystore

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your production key to Google APIs console

42:46:83:a4:13:53:78:45:71:46:74:A4:43:-- production key; com.package.name 32:56:73:B4:53:73:28:46:73:26:57:25:11:-- debug key; com.package.name